# Post Twitter using Twitteroauth doesn't post

Tags: php, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

I'm trying to post to Twitter using the twitteroauth library. Here's my script.

```
<?php
require_once('twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php');

$consumerKey    = 'xx';
$consumerSecret = 'xx';
$oAuthToken     = 'xx';
$oAuthSecret    = 'xx';

// Connect to Twitter
$connection = new TwitterOAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret,$oAuthToken, $oAuthSecret);

// Post Update
$content = $connection->post('statuses/update', array('status' => 'Test Tweet'));

var_export($connection->http_info);
?>
```

Export for debugging:

```
array ( 'url' => 'https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json', 'content_type' => 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'http_code' => 401, 'header_size' => 982, 'request_size' => 478, 'filetime' => -1, 'ssl_verify_result' => 0, 'redirect_count' => 0, 'total_time' => 0.376407, 'namelookup_time' => 0.017936, 'connect_time' => 0.098766, 'pretransfer_time' => 0.274227, 'size_upload' => 292, 'size_download' => 84, 'speed_download' => 223, 'speed_upload' => 775, 'download_content_length' => 84, 'upload_content_length' => 292, 'starttransfer_time' => 0.376153, 'redirect_time' => 0, )
```

The tweet doesn't post. I checked 10 times -- the access tokens are correct.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the url for posting a tweet to twitter is wrong since the API v1 is deprecated. You've to use API v1.1 to post a tweet. Fortunately, if you've downloaded the twitteroauth by any chance now, it is set already.

If not you have to set the version to 1.1

Goto twitteroauth.php and set the public $host to

```
public $host= "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/";
```

at line no 21.

Now your tweet url is

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json
```

Now tweet with the following connection string.

```
$content = $connection->post('statuses/update', array('status' => 'Test Tweet'));
```